# got some error massage in console when I try to update my field value in mongodb through express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-web-server

My node app will crash when i send req for update the field value in my mongo db.  The data will updated successfully, But The message will no show which is i provided in `(`
`(err) => {`
`if (err) {`
`res.status(500).json({`
`error: "There was an error in server side!",`
`});`
`} else {`
`res.status(200).json({`
`message: "value updated successfully!",`
`});`
`}`
`}`
`)`

Instead of showing above message. the mongo sent me `(const err = new MongooseError('Query was already executed: ' + str);). this message and more :`
`MongooseError: Query was already executed: Todo.updateOne({ _id: new ObjectId("6243ed2b5e0bdc9ab780b4d9...`

But I use each and every time different id and update with differen message.
when i check in db is that the old value updated or not, but nicely the old value updated. but no message or any thing i can't see in postman resposnse.Also in my console the mongodb throw me above error.

What ever happened I want to see my predefined err messages or successfully messages.

Comment: Can you provide code for your routes?

Comment: yes why not. (router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    await Todo.updateOne(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        {
            $set: {
                title: req.body.title,
            },
        },
        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json({
                    error: "There was an error in server side!",
                });
            } else {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: "todo fild value updated successfully!",
                });
            }
        }
    );
}); )

Comment: I solved it . But my solution is probably not a complete solution. Because if I remove the await keyword then everything is fair and lovely (The process works perfectly). So, Why should I remove this await keyword?

Comment: You are confused on using `async/await` and `callbacks`.

Comment: It’s hard to read in the comments but I believe you are using async await incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got and understood the answer. Actually, I am a beginner programmer and developer that's why I made this problem and it took a lot of time to solve. I solved the problem within 3-5 minutes by removing `async/await` but I took a lot of time to dig out why it's working after removing async/await. Here is a basic concept of asynchronous programming if we use `async/await` we don't have to use callback again, Or if we use callback we don't need async/await Because it's just redundant. So, if we want to get data like we are getting from

```
callback(err,data) =>{
res.send(data);
}
```

then we just assigned our full thing in a variable like:

```
try{
const data=await (our code);
res.send(data);
}catch(err){
res.send(err.message);
}
```